# Is there a word like biped that applies to creatures that move like snakes?

Tags: single-word-requests

The SAT version of my question would be this analogy:

> Fill in the blanks:
>
> 1) human : biped :: snake : **__**

The best I've gotten is "legless vertebrate" but I was hoping a single word answer.

Comment: How about _noped_?

Comment: Is noped with that meaning even in the urban dictionary?

Comment: No, that's why it was a comment, just a bad pun. _Limbless_ or _legless_ should work, they are exact equivalents of _biped_ which means having two legs (feet actually but you get the idea). We could give you better options if you gave some more context.

Comment: The only noun I can come up with is "serpent," but that only refers to reptiles. "Limbless" and "legless" are both single-word answers, but they're adjectives. I think I'm a fan of "noped."

Comment: *legless vertebrates* seems the accepted term. See also: "Snakes and other legless reptiles are considered tetrapods because they are sufficiently like other reptiles that have a full complement of limbs." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapod)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but you could try monoped, since gastropods (which are similarly limblesss) have their name origin in being "stomach-legged".  But again, I'd tread with caution on that one.

Comment: @Zibbobz _monoped_ would mean it has one leg, not none.

Comment: @terdon Hence why I wouldn't recommend it.  Just felt like adding a bit of bological knowledge in case it would help.

Comment: @Zibbobz given the enormous diversity of gastropods I would not be surprised if some do have a form of limb. In fact, some _do_ have something called an 'accessory limb'. Invertebrate anatomy is not my field though so I am not entirely sure what that is. In any case, snakes are certainly not gastropods, despite not having limbs :).

Comment: @terdon I did invite biological discussion into this, didn't I?  Hah. ;) Duly noted. I'm rather glad now that I didn't include it in my answer.  I'm more convinced than ever that it is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because biped describes structure and stance, but not motion per se. There are many bipedal modes of locomotion. Similarly, there are many apodal modes of locomotion. Snake motions are mostly divided into four types, but there are other legless critters with their own means of getting around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fit to your title, I would say, is *serpentine*.  That doesn't fit your SAT-style version though, it's equivalent to *bipedally*.

Comment: I'm torn between this answer and Zibbobz' answer as this is the word I will use. I'm going to pick this answer because it points out that my "cool SAT analogy" is completely wrong. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 6):

Snake is an [Apod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Apod)

> Without feet; footless.

Comment: Nice one, +1! Unfortunately, my _Henderson's dictionary of biological terms_ defines _apoda_ as: "n. an order of limbless burrowing amphibians [...] having a reduced or absent larval stage and minute calcified scales in the skin. [...] The name has also been given to orders of parasitic barnacles (crustaceans) and burrowing sea cucumbers (echinoderms)". However, it also lists the adjective _apodal_  as: "having no feet; having no ventral fin, of fishes; stemless". According to the definition you cite, it looks like a snake is not _an apod (noun)_ but is is _an apod (adjective) animal_.

Comment: @terdon Yes, leave it to eighteenth and nineteenth century zoologists to make the terminology more complex than it need be.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [Limbless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limbless)?

> 1. (zoology) not possessing limbs

Or perhaps [*legless*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/legless)?

> 1. without legs

Comment: Neither fits the analogy very well.

Comment: @jmucchiello I don't really understand what you're looking for. Do you need a noun? Could you use an actual example sentence instead of this "SAT version"? From an etymological perspective, the word you are looking for is _serpent_ since it comes from an Ancient Greek word meaning to _slither_. However, in modern English that only applies to snakes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the word [serpentine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/serpentine) - Of or resembling a serpent, as in **form** or movement.

There isn't really a prefix form for 'none', which is why you can't really find an "xPed" form for serpent (like biped, triped, or quadraped).

Important Note: Serpentine specifically describes a quality of snake-ness, and though they're well-known for leglessness, the term "limbless" or "legless" would probably be preferred for a specific nature of having no limbs upon which one moves.

Comment: This is the word I'll be using but I picked Chris H's answer for the reason listed in the comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find the precise word after a good deal of searching, but here's what I suggest by extension from the Latin that we use for other numbers of legs (such as *biped* and *tripod*): *nullaped*, from the Latin *nulla* (literally *nothing*, one of the Latin words for *zero* or *none*).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the word you are looking for is *tetrapod*?

*Some tetrapods, [like whales and snakes](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/vertebrates/tetrapods/tetraintro.html), have lost some or all of the four limbs that their ancestors had, but because of their ancestry they are still grouped as tetrapods.*

Comment: OED defines this as '*a four-footed animal, especially a member of a group that includes all vertebrates higher than fishes.*'

Comment: oh, wait... Dictionary.com says '*Most tetrapods have two pairs of limbs, though some, such as whales and snakes, have lost one or both pairs. Tetrapods include the amphibians, reptiles, birds, mammals, and various extinct groups, and evolved from lobe-finned fish during the late Devonian Period.*'

Comment: humans and snakes are both tetrapods. This doesn't seem to fit the analogy

Comment: @sumelic - I offered tetrapod on the basis that the human : biped example refers to limbs, so on the  principle of parallelism the blank should also refer to limbs.

Answer (score 0):

Aristotle divided animals (one kind of division) in apods (limless creatures, fishes, serpents and cetaceans), bipeds (man, birds), and tetrapods (reptiles and mammals) 
So the technical work you need is "apod"
best regards
Jorge Ferigolo

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I think a good word is apodous (*Adj. of snakes and fish; naturally footless*).

Here you can refer to these species as apodous fish/reptiles, or as 'limbless vertebrates'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can [edit] this into your existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just a thought. I think it would be neat if they made a noun for this. There isn't one as far as I know.

I think they should add this to the dictionary: Nulliped. *From Latin; 'nulli' meaning 'none' and 'ped' meaning 'foot'.*

Woops, comment above answered my own question. There is a noun: 'apod'.

I guess this is the noun form of the adjective apodous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

'Leg-less' usually refers to legless lizards. Some snakes move by curving back and forth on themselves ... in a serpentine manner. Some snakes are 'side-winders' ... curving sideways and moving on a diagonal.